# Is there a way to give persistenceUnitName for Spring's LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean without persistence.xml?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have multiple datasources and multiple EntityManagerFactories to be defined in my spring context.

If there is only on EntityManagerFactory we don't need to give persistenceUnitName. But to associate EntityManager to correct EntityManagerFactory with @PersistenceContext I should give unitName="somePU" attribute.

But if we give name for persistenceUnitName attribute then Spring is expecting these persistenceUnitName declarations in persistence.xml file.

Is there a way to give persistenceUnitName for Spring's LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean without persistence.xml?

Also I found another issue when I used persistence.xml with Spring's LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean. The packagesToScan property is not working. I need to list down all the Entity classes in persistence.xml.

Any idea why it is happening?

-siva

Comment: I guess, when specifying a persistence.xml the JPA scanning is used instead of the spring scanning.

Comment: Actually why spring need the persistenceUnitName to be presented in persistence.xml? Anyway It doesn't contain anything except unit-name.

Answer (score 4):

Specifying property in `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` works for me

```
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyPersistenceUnit"/>
```

Comment: If we give name for persistenceUnitName attribute then Spring is expecting these persistenceUnitName declarations in persistence.xml file. Is it doable without persistence.xml?

Comment: Does it throw some exception or message in the logs? I have completely removed persistence.xml from my project. Everything is configured just with LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.

Comment: But I had to remove persistence.xml from my project. If its present it somehow conflicts with Spring, even if I don't reference it anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

After creating the LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean, set the persistence unit name:

```
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    factory.setPersistenceUnitName("NAME_OF_PERSISTENCE_UNIT");
```